# Get Minimum and Maximum value per group in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, max, min

I need to get amount attached to minimum and maximum date column per grouping by `Property_externalID` and `Lease_ExternalID`.

How would I go about doing this?

Example: result should return one row per grouping:

```
Property_ExternalID Lease_ExternalID    Min_Amount      Max_Amount
------------------------------------------------------------------
27050               27050-0200          23              .02
```

Table sample data:

```
Property_ExternalID Lease_ExternalID    PropertyAssetId Date        Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
27050               27050-0200          6097            10/1/2017   23
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2019    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2021    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2022    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2023    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2024    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2025    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2027    0.02
27050               27050-0200          6097            4/1/2026    0.02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always helpful to provide some basic SQL statement to create the tables and data so that those helping you out can try different things.  Like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
 Property_ExternalID    VARCHAR(15),
 Lease_ExternalID   VARCHAR(15),
 PropertyAssetId    VARCHAR(15),
 Date           DATE,
 Amount         DECIMAL(10, 2)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '10/1/2017', 23)  
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2019', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2021', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2022', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2023', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2024', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2025', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2027', 0.02)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('27050', '27050-0200', '6097', '04/1/2026', 0.02)
```

Given that, you need to join from your main table to a subquery where you have determined what the **minimum** date is for each `Property_ExternalID` and `Lease_ExternalID`. Then you need to join to your main table again (since the minimum and maximum values for Date will likely be different) and then to another subquery where you have determined what the **maximum** date is for each `Property_ExternalID` and `Lease_ExternalID`.

Something like this...

```
SELECT a.Property_ExternalID, a.Lease_ExternalID, a.Amount AS 'Min_Amount', b.Amount AS 'Max_Amount'
FROM #Temp a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Property_ExternalID, Lease_ExternalID, MIN(Date) AS MinDate 
    FROM #Temp 
    GROUP BY  Property_ExternalID, Lease_ExternalID
) x ON a.Property_ExternalID = x.Property_ExternalID AND a.Lease_ExternalID = x.Lease_ExternalID AND a.Date = x.MinDate
INNER JOIN #Temp b ON a.Property_ExternalID = b.Property_ExternalID AND a.Lease_ExternalID = b.Lease_ExternalID
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Property_ExternalID, Lease_ExternalID, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate 
    FROM #Temp 
    GROUP BY  Property_ExternalID, Lease_ExternalID
) y ON b.Property_ExternalID = y.Property_ExternalID AND b.Lease_ExternalID = y.Lease_ExternalID AND b.Date = y.MaxDate
```

Noel

Comment: This worked!  Sorry for not getting back to you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MIN and MAX [aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql) along with a GROUP BY clause. This should work for you...

```
DECLARE @MyDate AS DATE

-- comment the next line out if you want all dates
SET @MyDate = '04/01/2021'

SELECT Property_ExternalID, Lease_ExternalID, Date, MIN(Amount) AS 'Min_Amount',
MAX(Amount) AS 'Max_Amount'
FROM YourTable
WHERE Date = COALESCE(@MyDate, Date)
GROUP BY Property_ExternalID, Lease_ExternalID, Date
```

Noel

Comment: I realized I forgot one important requirement.  I need to get min and max based on date value.  Is that possible with a simple grouping?

Comment: Sure, anything is possible. ;-)

Do you want the min and max for one date or all dates? I updated my answer to be flexible and handle both possibilities.

Comment: I am looking for a value that is attached to minimum and maximum dates. If I remove "Date" grouping from your query, it shows .02 as min and 23 as max.  It should be other way around because 23 is associated with the minimum date and .02 is associated with maximum date.  Also, I am only looking to return just one line.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you wanted. I'll submit another answer with what I think will work for you.